# Using VTK to create Visualisation similar to Roll-Mode of Oscilloscopes

Tags: 3d, data-visualization, vtk

I would like to use VTK to create a data visualisation similar to the roll mode of an oscilloscope. Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kn0j3gE1jg8&t=178s

1. In the first step, I would like to create a simple plot for a trajectory in a 2D plane. It would be nice if the points of the trajectory vanish after some time (similar to the phosphorescence afterglow effect of old oscilloscopes with phosphor screens). Example application: Visualisation of the trajectory of an airplane on the ground.
2. In the second step I would like to extend this concept to the three-dimensional space with multiplie trajectories. Example application: Visualisation of the trajectory of several airplanes in the air. However, real-time visualisation is not necessary.

I am currently a bit unsure where to start. I would prefer Python as programming language but C++ would be also ok. I have not so much experience with 3D rendering which is why I thought VTK might be the easiest option for this. Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at the [vedo](https://vedo.embl.es/#gallery) examples, if you're ok with doing it in python:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that looks pretty neat! I'm a bit sceptical because vedo does look very new so that one might guess that it is not so well tested. I will give it a try nonetheless

Comment: The problem could be solved with vedo without bigger problems. Nice package!